# Casting a type for result in a generic method from httpClient request

Tags: c#, generics, types

If I wanted to use a generic method to make an http request using an httpClient how would you cast the content returned from the request to the proper return type.

This works, but it seems strange to check for typeof(T)

EDIT: after reading about System.Net.Http.Formatters namespace. I have added the class library to my solution in order to utilize the "ReadAsAsync" method for my generic return statement. 
However, now there is an issue with the formatters overload, and it wants me to use Newtonsoft.Json in this function. Although Newtonsoft is added to my solution in another class library, the class library which contains this function doesn't reference it. What sorts of overloads should be used here?

```
public async Task<T> GetUrlData<T>(string url)
    {
        var result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(null, typeof(T));
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var byteArray =
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config.SecurityCameraCredentialsUserName + ":" +
                                        config.SecurityCameraCredentialsPassword);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();//Errors here
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`ReadAsAsync<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/hh944534%28v%3dvs.108%29)?

Comment: Woah, as soon as i see a bunch typeof(T) checks in a generic call i get cold shivers. 96.43534534% of the time it means there is something wrong

Comment: @TheGeneral PTGS ;) Post traumatic generics......

Comment: @Nkosi hahaha nice

Comment: @JohnWu Where do you see a `.Result` call?

Comment: Yeah PTGS. That's why I've posted my question. I knew it was all wrong. 
 I've added the Formatting Extention DLL to my project inorder to access ReadAsAsync<T>  , but something is still not right.

Comment: @user2224583 please update the question

Comment: I think, the initialisation of `var result` should be `var result = default;` or `var result = default(T)`.